# CakePHP3のAuthコンポーネントでContoller名称とは異なるテーブルを認証対象テーブルにする方法

Tags: php, cakephp

お世話になります。

現在CakePHP3でAuthコンポーネントを用いたログイン処理を作成しております。

ネット上によくあるサンプルコードなどで提示されている「users」というテーブルを作成し
下記のようなコントローラとモデルを作成することでログイン認証は行えました。
Controller: UsersController.php
Model: 
Table>UsersTable.php
Entity>User.php

ただ、今回決まっているテーブル名称のテーブルに対して認証処理を行いたいのですが
下記のような形式にしてもControllerの名称の頭部分の名称のテーブルを参照しようとしてエラーが発生します。
エラー内容：Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '[db名].login' doesn't exist
Controller: LoginController.php
Model: 
Table>AccountsTable.php
Entity>Accout.php

上記のような形式で、LoginController.phpでAccountsテーブルを認証対象のテーブルにすることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

認証ハンドラの設定 | CakePHP CookBook 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/controllers/components/authentication.html#id5

`userModel` オプションで認証に利用するTableクラスを指定できます。

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Accounts'],
    'Form'
]);
```

Comment: 無事に認証対象のテーブル変更してのログインが実現できました。ありがとうございました。